# How to get unique values with many different URLs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I have a dataframe that looks something like the one below.

```
    Product    URLs                          Company
0   shoes      www.walmart.com/12va15a       walmart
1   shoes      www.costco.com/1apsd-dfasx    costco   
2   pants      www.amazon.com/adsffa1        NaN
3   shirt      www.Amazon.com/fas19axl       Amazon 
4   shoes      www.walmart.com/ywsg141q      NaN
```

I'm not sure if Pandas can get the **unique variables in the URL column** and fill it into the NaNs in the **company column.**

The dataframe that I will like looks like that below

```
    Product    URLs                          Company
0   shoes      www.walmart.com/12va15a       walmart
1   shoes      www.costco.com/1apsd-dfasx    costco   
2   pants      www.amazon.com/adsffa1        amazon
3   shirt      www.Amazon.com/fas19axl       amazon 
4   shoes      www.walmart.com/ywsg141q      walmart
```

Edit: I have lowered all the URLs but i'm not sure how just extract the keywords like Amazon, costco, etc. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for values between first and second `.`:

```
df.Company = df.URLs.str.lower().str.extract('\.(.+)\.', expand=False)
print (df)
  Product                        URLs  Company
0   shoes     www.walmart.com/12va15a  walmart
1   shoes  www.costco.com/1apsd-dfasx   costco
2   pants      www.amazon.com/adsffa1   amazon
3   shirt     www.Amazon.com/fas19axl   amazon
4   shoes    www.walmart.com/ywsg141q  walmart
```

If want replace only missing values also use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df.Company = df.Company.fillna(df.URLs.str.lower().str.extract('\.(.+)\.', expand=False))
```

Answer (score 2):

`lower` your URLs before processing:

```
df.URLs = df.URLs.str.lower()
```

Comment: yeap but i'm not exactly sure how to process from there .. haha i just lowered it